# UI disappears when passing message in node-red ui-template in angular

Tags: angularjs, node-red

I have a large list, and I am formatting it as a table in Node-Red Dashboard using a ui-template. I use md-button for each line, to generate a button so the user can do something with that line in the table.
My template is rather simple:

```
<style>
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #cce6ff; vertical-align: text-top; border-bottom: 1px solid #6699ff;}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #fffff; vertical-align: text-top; border-bottom: 1px solid #6699ff;}
</style>
```

```html
<div height="250" style="height: 250px;">
    <table>
        <tr><th>Time</th><th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Action</th></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in msg.payload track by $index">
            <td style="white-space: nowrap">{{row.peTime}}</td>
            <td style="white-space: nowrap">{{row.peTitle}}</td>
            <td>{{row.peLong}}</td>
            <td><md-button ng-click="send({payload: row.peTime});">Click me</md-button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Everything looks fine in the UI, but when I click the button sometimes at first, sometimes after a few clicks the entire table content disappears from the browser.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Could it be that some component is out of date? I have a full example flow here: https://pastebin.com/cibBa5NG

Comment: it will be great if you can add a working code snippet.

Comment: It is hard to help find bugs in the `send({payload: row.peTime})` function when the question contains none of the buggy code.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure what you mean. I put all my code to the pastebin link above.

Comment: Strange, I get the problem on every button click. No console errors either. Needs someone with better Angular skills than me I'm afraid. That's why I've mainly stopped using Dashboard because I constantly butt heads with Angular which is far too complex. I suggest raising in the forum in case anyone there can help.

Comment: @JulianKnight I did that (in the forum), but the response was pretty much the same. Nobody really digs deep into Angular to tell what has gone wrong. So far I replaced this view with ui-table, which almost do the same, but this would be more elegant.

Comment: Unfortunately, Angular is extremely complex Csongor and the advantage of Dashboard is also its main issue. All the complexity is hidden and basic UI's are immensely simple. But you reach a "cliff edge" where you push the thing too hard and it flips from easy to impossible very quickly. This is the reason I created node-red-contrib-uibuilder so that people had an alternative which takes the opposite approach. It is both lighter in weight and more flexible but you have to build your own UI. Though I provide a starting template & lots of examples.

Comment: Thanks for your insight @JulianKnight. What would be the technology you would recommend to use when Dashboard is not enough? Something which would still work relatively well with Node-Red?

Comment: Well, as the author of node-red-contrib-uibuilder, I would naturally recommend that! But in truth, if you have even just some basic HMTL/JavaScript skills, you should be able to build any kind of web app/ui with uibuilder. You get a front-end library that handles the complexity of websocket comms with Node-RED, an editor, some tools for serving front-end libraries and it comes with VueJS/bootstrap-vue but that's easily replaced with your fav. framework. Next big release will have a built-in security framework too. Handling websocket security correctly. Lighter but more flexible than Dashboard.